# Need to convert valid date values and error out invalid values in Python

Tags: python, strptime

I am using Python3.6 `datetime.datetime.strptime` to parse different input date values based on provided format. 
Below is the code I am using.

```
def date_convert(dt, fmt):
    outdict = {'result': '', 'error': ''}
    try:
        outdict['result'] = datetime.strptime(dt, fmt)
    except Exception:
        outdict['error'] = 'Invalid input date value, expected format is ' + fmt
```

I am facing two issues with above code

1. Can not recognize invalid date values for %Y%m%d, %y%m%d, %Y%m%d %H:%M and few more formats. In Java we have setLenient option which will help us to match to exact and convert 
   Ex: `date_convert('181223', '%Y%m%d')` 
   For above input I am getting output as 1812-02-03 00:00:00 but I need to get output as invalid format. How to achieve this
2. Few times I will be getting two or three date formats with in a specific column for few data files. For this I want to pass list of formats so that which ever format matches that should be used and converted. 
   Ex:Below is are values of a single field coming in file. I want to pass somthing like ['%Y%m%d','%m-%d-%y','%d-%b-%Y'] and convert all input values

   > Date_Field
   >   2018-23-04 
   >   2018-14-04 
   >   03-17-18 
   >   12-29-17
   >   25-Mar-2018
   >   29-Jan-2018

Thanks,
Raghunath.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the **[dateutil](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)** module.

**Demo:**

```
from dateutil import parser
d = ['2018-23-04', '2018-14-04', '03-17-18', '12-29-17', '25-Mar-2018', '29-Jan-2018']
for i in d:
    print( parser.parse(i, dayfirst=True))
```

or **[dateparser](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/)**

**Demo:**

```
import dateparser
d = ['2018-23-04', '2018-14-04', '03-17-18', '12-29-17', '25-Mar-2018', '29-Jan-2018']
for i in d:
    print( dateparser.parse(i))
```

**Output:**

```
2018-04-23 00:00:00
2018-04-14 00:00:00
2018-03-17 00:00:00
2017-12-29 00:00:00
2018-03-25 00:00:00
2018-01-29 00:00:00
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I already used this module. This function can't handle formats like %m%d%Y Ex: parser.parse('03232018') and very slow compared to datetime.strptime

Comment: Rakesh, I am getting ValueError: month must be in 1..12 for parser.parse('03232018'). How to give format for this module

Comment: I meant the second option `import dateparser` --> `dateparser.parse('03232018') `

Comment: print(dateparser.parse('181223',['%Y%m%d']))  -- Output : 1812-02-03 00:00:00. Expected to fail

Comment: `print(dateparser.parse('181223',['%y%m%d']))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173545/discussion-between-raghunath-and-rakesh).

Comment: Sorry I cannot access chat

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I have thousands of files. For which I got schema from client with date formats for each date field. But often I see date values not consistent. Ex: They provide %Y%m%d in schema but in data we may have values like 20180321, 181221 (may be invalid), 1821 (invalid). I need to convert to null if it is not matching.
Previously I was using Java which has setLenient, was worked for me in this data issue. java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd"); 
sdf.setLenient(false).Currently